# Почему Webpack как-то криво отображает ошибки, и как это исправить?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webpack, babel

Специально допустил синтаксическую ошибку в коде, чтобы продемонстрировать вывод в консоль.

[image]

Слишком много мусора и ничего не понятно по поводу самой ошибки. Какие-то квадратики, "m"-ки и вообще очень странное и кривое форматирование. **Откуда это берется и как это побороть?**

Конфиг абсолютно тривиален: просто Vue-приложение.

```js
const Path = require("path");
const VueLoaderPlugin = require("vue-loader/lib/plugin");

module.exports = {
  mode: "development",

  entry: Path.join(__dirname, "main.js"),

  output: {
    path: Path.join(__dirname, "dist"),
    filename: "main.js"
  },

  module: {
    rules: [{
        test: /\.js$/,
        use: "babel-loader"
      },

      {
        test: /\.vue$/,
        use: "vue-loader"
      },

      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        use: [
          "vue-style-loader",
          "css-loader"
        ]
      }
    ]
  },

  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "vue-custom-context-menu": Path.join(__dirname, "..", "src")
    }
  },

  plugins: [
    new VueLoaderPlugin()
  ]
};
```

Comment: Ну webpack здесь наверняка совершенно не при чем. Это очень похоже на проблемы со шрифтами в выводе в консоль.  Не утверждаю, но очень похоже. 
Попробуйте запустить сборку в другом эмуляторе консоли, отличным от того который вы используете. 
Так же возможно стоит обратить внимание на настройку локали. Не могу сказать точнее про причину, но я бы стал искать именно тут, в настройках рабочей машины, нежели в софте. Или я еще подумал о том что это могут быть какие то управляющие символы форматирующие вывод, которые не поддерживает консоль по каким то причинам.

Comment: @zalex > *Или я еще подумал о том что это могут быть какие то управляющие символы форматирующие вывод* - так и есть. Это color-коды, которые мой терминал прекрасно понимает, а вот хромовская консоль отображает в виде текста. Вопрос лишь в том, что делать. Пробовал изменять значение Webpack'ового `stats: {colors: /**/ }`, но это не помогло почему-то.

Comment: А вот тут посмотрите.https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/837

Comment: @zalex благодарю, вот что-то подобное и искал. Сегодня попробую и отпишу Вам. Спасибо за участие

Comment: Обязательно напишите, будет интересно. Как раз сейчас сажусь за vue :)

Comment: @zalex попробовал разные варианты, ничего не помогло. Возможно потому, что они описаны в 2015 году и уже давно не работают. Что ж, буду продолжать искать решение.